# copy and paste resultant column into another spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering if it is possible for someone to help me shorten the code as i'm afraid it might take a long time to run after i add in other codes. What i want to do will be explain in the following:

I want to copy say test2 (do take note that the spacing means the variables are on their own row and column)

```
test1 1 2 1
test2 2 1 4
test3 1 1 1
```

After copying it I will paste it at some other sheet.

Let say, I have another set of results
Say

```
test2 2 1 4
test3 3 9 8
test5 1 1 1
```

I wanted to copy test2 but my VBA coding werent able to as it still assumes that test2 is at 2nd row.

And one last case would be, if test2 not available, it will continue on copying the rest of the result and paste it at other sheets.

I have did some coding, do run through and help me solve this problem. THANKS!

```
Sub Macro1()

 iMaxRow = 6 ' or whatever the max is.
    'Don't make too large because this will slow down your code.

    ' Loop through columns and rows
    For iCol = 1 To 1 ' or however many columns you have
        For iRow = 1 To 1

        With Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(iRow, iCol)
            ' Check that cell is not empty.
            If .Value = "Bin1" Then
                Range("A1:G1").Select
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets("sheet4").Select
                Range("A1").Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Sheets("sheet3").Select
            ElseIf .Value = "Bin2" Then
                Range("A1:G1").Select
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets("sheet4").Select
                Range("A1").Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Sheets("sheet3").Select
            ElseIf .Value = "Bin3" Then
               Range("A1:G1").Select
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets("sheet4").Select
                Range("A1").Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Sheets("sheet3").Select
            ElseIf .Value = "Bin4" Then
                Range("A1:G1").Select
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets("sheet4").Select
                Range("A1").Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Sheets("sheet3").Select
            ElseIf .Value = "Bin5" Then
                Range("A1:G1").Select
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets("sheet4").Select
                Range("A1").Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Sheets("sheet3").Select
            ElseIf .Value = "Bin6" Then
                Range("A1:G1").Select
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets("sheet4").Select
                Range("A1").Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Sheets("sheet3").Select
            End If



        End With

    Next iRow
    Next iCol

For iCol1 = 1 To 1 ' or however many columns you have
        For iRow1 = 1 To 2

        With Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(iRow1, iCol1)
            ' Check that cell is not empty.

                If .Value = "Bin2" Then
                Range("A2:G2").Select
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets("sheet4").Select
                Range("A2").Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Sheets("sheet3").Select
            ElseIf .Value = "Bin3" Then
                Range("A2:G2").Select
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets("sheet4").Select
                Range("A2").Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Sheets("sheet3").Select
            ElseIf .Value = "Bin4" Then
               Range("A2:G2").Select
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets("sheet4").Select
                Range("A2").Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Sheets("sheet3").Select
            ElseIf .Value = "Bin5" Then
               Range("A2:G2").Select
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets("sheet4").Select
                Range("A2").Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Sheets("sheet3").Select
            ElseIf .Value = "Bin6" Then
                Range("A2:G2").Select
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets("sheet4").Select
                Range("A2").Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Sheets("sheet3").Select
            End If

        End With

    Next iRow1
    Next iCol1

For iCol2 = 1 To 1 ' or however many columns you have
        For iRow2 = 1 To 3

        With Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(iRow2, iCol2)
            ' Check that cell is not empty.

                If .Value = "Bin3" Then
                Range("A3:G3").Select
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets("sheet4").Select
                Range("A3").Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Sheets("sheet3").Select
            ElseIf .Value = "Bin4" Then
               Range("A3:G3").Select
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets("sheet4").Select
                Range("A3").Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Sheets("sheet3").Select
            ElseIf .Value = "Bin5" Then
                Range("A3:G3").Select
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets("sheet4").Select
                Range("A3").Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Sheets("sheet3").Select
            ElseIf .Value = "Bin6" Then
                Range("A3:G3").Select
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets("sheet4").Select
                Range("A3").Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Sheets("sheet3").Select
            End If

        End With

    Next iRow2
    Next iCol2

For iCol3 = 1 To 1 ' or however many columns you have
        For iRow3 = 1 To 4

        With Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(iRow3, iCol3)
            ' Check that cell is not empty.

                If .Value = "Bin4" Then
                Range("A4:G4").Select
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets("sheet4").Select
                Range("A4").Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Sheets("sheet3").Select
            ElseIf .Value = "Bin5" Then
                Range("A4:G4").Select
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets("sheet4").Select
                Range("A4").Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Sheets("sheet3").Select
            ElseIf .Value = "Bin6" Then
                Range("A4:G4").Select
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets("sheet4").Select
                Range("A4").Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Sheets("sheet3").Select
            End If

        End With

    Next iRow3
    Next iCol3

For iCol4 = 1 To 1 ' or however many columns you have
        For iRow4 = 1 To 5

        With Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(iRow4, iCol4)
            ' Check that cell is not empty.

                If .Value = "Bin5" Then
                Range("A5:G5").Select
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets("sheet4").Select
                Range("A5").Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Sheets("sheet3").Select
            ElseIf .Value = "Bin6" Then
                Range("A5:G5").Select
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets("sheet4").Select
                Range("A5").Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Sheets("sheet3").Select
            End If

        End With

    Next iRow4
    Next iCol4

For iCol5 = 1 To 1 ' or however many columns you have
        For iRow5 = 1 To 6

        With Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(iRow5, iCol5)
            ' Check that cell is not empty.

                If .Value = "Bin6" Then
                 Range("A6:G6").Select
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets("sheet4").Select
                Range("A6").Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Sheets("sheet3").Select
            End If

        End With

    Next iRow5
    Next iCol5
Sheets("Sheet4").Select
Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am struggling to identify what your code does.  Below I specify some simplifications and other necessary improvements but there may be more once we have cleared the brushwood.

**Change 1**

Please use `Option Explicit` and please declare your variables.  This avoids a misspelt variable being taken as a new implicit declaration.

**Change 2**

Please use `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`.  This avoids repainting the screen as the macro works through its tasks.  This would have been essential with your code because of all the switching between sheets.  It is less important with my code because I do not switch sheets.

**Change 3**

Replace:

```
With Sheets("Sheet3")
  :
  Range("A1:G1").Select
  Selection.Copy
  Sheets("sheet4").Select
  Range("A1").Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste
  Sheets("sheet3").Select
  :
End With
```

by:

```
With Sheets("Sheet3")
  :
  .Range("A1:G1").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A1")
  :
End With
```

This avoids switching sheets which is the biggest waste of time.

**Change 4**

For each If-ElseIf-ElseIf-EndIf you do the same copy.  So:

```
If .Value = "Bin1" Or .Value = "Bin2" Or .Value = "Bin3" _
   .Value = "Bin4" Or .Value = "Bin5"                   Then
```

would have the same effect.

**Summary so far**

I believe the following does exactly the same as your first loop:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Macro1()
  Dim iCol As Long
  Dim iRow As Long
  Dim ValueCell as String

  With Sheets("Sheet3")
    For iCol = 1 To 1
      For iRow = 1 To 1
        ValueCell = .Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
        If ValueCell = "Bin1" Or ValueCell = "Bin2" Or ValueCell = "Bin3" Or _
           ValueCell = "Bin4" Or ValueCell = "Bin5"                   Then
         .Range("A1:G1").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A1")
        End If
      Next
    Next
  End With

End Sub
```

**Possible further change**

Are the loops really independent?  To me it looks as though you could merge them into a single loop.

**New section added in response to exchange of comments**

Consider the code in your question:

- You have six double loops.
- In every case, the outer loop is `For iCol = 1 to 1`.  That is, you only examine column "A" although you imply you would examine more columns if the code was faster.
- The inner loop is `For iRow = 1 to №`.  № is 1 in the first loop, 2 in the second and 6 in the sixth loop.  Again you imply you would examine more rows if the code was faster.
- The action for each loop depends on the value of №.

Table showing effect of № of action:

```
Value
 of №   Cells examined   Values checked for   Range moved
   1    A1               "Bin1" ... "Bin6"    A1:G1
   2    A1, A2           "Bin2" ... "Bin6"    A2:G2
   3    A1, A2, A3       "Bin3" ... "Bin6"    A3:G3
   4    A1, A2, ... A4   "Bin4" ... "Bin6"    A4:G4
   5    A1, A2, ... A5   "Bin5", "Bin6"       A5:G5
   6    A1, A2, ... A6   "Bin6"               A6:G6
```

- That is, in double loop №, you examine cells A1 to A№, check for values "Bin№" to "Bin6" and if found, you copy `Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A№:G№")` to `Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A№)`.

In your text and example data, you refer to "text2" instead of "Bin2".  I do not understand what you are trying to do.  Below, I introduce some more VBA which may help you create the code you want.  If it does not, you will have to add a new section to your question explaining in English what you are trying to do.

**New syntax 1**

Consider:

```
For iRow = 1 to 6
    :
  .Range("A6:G6").Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A6")
    :
Next
```

`"A6:G6"` and `"A6"` are strings that you can build at runtime.

Now consider:

```
For iRow = 1 to iRowMax
    :
  .Range("A" & iRowMax & ":G" & iRowMax)).Copy _
                         Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A" & iRowMax)
    :
Next
```

According to the value of iRowMax this gives:

```
iRow    Statement    
  1     .Range("A1:G1")).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A1")
  2     .Range("A2:G2")).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A2")
  3     .Range("A3:G3")).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A3")
```

**New syntax 2**

Another way of changing a range at runtime is to replace:

```
.Range(string)
```

with

```
.Range(.Cells(RowTop,ColLeft),.Cells(RowBottom,ColRight))
```

With this syntax you can easily specify a rectangle of the size required.

**New syntax 3**

Consider:

```
For i = 1 to 5
  If this(i) = that Then
    Do something fixed
    Exit For
  End If
Next
' Exit For statement jumps to here
```

In this loop, I am testing five values.  If any match, I do something.  If I get a match on the first value, I do not need to check the other values.  `Exit For` allows me to jump out of the For-Loop.  If there are nested For-Loops, `Exit For` only exits the inner loop

**New syntax 4**

`"Bin1"`, `"Bin2"` and so on can also be created at runtime.

```
iRowMax = 4
For iRow = 1 to iRowMax
  For iBin = iRowMax to 6
    If ValueCell = "Bin" & iBin Then
      ' Move Range
      Exit For
    End If 
  Next
  ' Exit For statement jumps to here
Next
```

With iRow = 4, the inner For-Loop sets iBin to 4, 5 and 6.  This sets `"Bin" & iBin` to `"Bin4"`, `"Bin5"` and `"Bin6"`.

So:

```
  For BinNum = iRowMax to 6
    If ValueCell = "Bin" & BinNum Then
      ' Move Range
      Exit For
    End If 
  Next
```

is the same as:

```
  If ValueCell = "Bin4" Or ValueCell = "Bin5" Or ValueCell = "Bin6" Then
    ' Move Range
  End If
```

This new code is more complicated and is more difficult to understand than the original, but it may be what you need.

**Summary**

I have shown you different ways of changing what happens depending on the value of iRow.  I hope one of them will allow you to build the routine you want.

I have not tested it but I think this does the same as all six loops in your original code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Macro1()
  Dim iBin as Long
  Dim iCol As Long
  Dim iRow As Long
  Dim iRowMax as Long
  Dim ValueCell as String

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  With Sheets("Sheet3")
    For iRowMax = 1 to 6
      For iCol = 1 To 1     ' This could be replaced by iCol = 1 at the top
        For iRow = 1 To iRowMax
          ValueCell = .Cells(iRow, iCol).Value
          For iBin = iRowMax to 6
            If ValueCell = "Bin" & iBin Then
              .Range("A" & iRowMax & ":G" & iRowMax)).Copy _
                      Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("A" & iRowMax)
            End If
          Next iBin
        Next iRow
     Next iCol
  End With
End Sub
```

Note: only removing all the Select statements makes this code faster than yours.  The other changes make it smaller and very slightly slower because I have two extra For-Loops and I am building strings at runtime.

Comment: Btw, I have tried doing in a single loop. It did not show the result i wanted.

Comment: And to add on, I have tried another loop using
 If ValueCell = "Bin2" Or ValueCell = "Bin3" Or _
           ValueCell = "Bin4" Or ValueCell = "Bin5"                   Then

I tried using other variables such as test, it seems like the if statement fails. It still shows inside the excel file

Comment: Please note that I have not seen your data.  For example, the data in your question does not include "Bin1" or "Bin5".  So I cannot diagnose the problem.  Perhaps the loops only look as though they can be combined.  Do you know how to use the debugger?  Stop on the If.  Is the value of ValueCell what you expect?  If you keep the original loops but simplify them in the way I simplified the first, does that give the result you want?

Comment: Hi Tony, I'm sorry about the use of variables. Bin1 = test1 and so on... I was just trying to use different names. I have not use the debugger before, but i have tried doing the same loop with your simplified version. It did work. Thank you! :)
But for the problem that i surface out on my last comment, it actually copied another variable name not inside the if loop, for example, a name called experiment.
In other words
Bin1       1 2 3
Bin3       1 2 3
Experiment 1 2 3
it actually copies experiment when its not declare in the if loop. I hope you understand what i'm trying to say.

Comment: The code shown in your question, examines every cell within a rectangle. If any cell within that rectangle is "Bin1" or "Bin2" or "Bin3" or "Bin4" or "Bin5", it copies Range("A1:G1") to Sheets("Sheet4").  You only need **one** cell in the rectangle to be "Bin#" and the range is copied.  Do you mean to copy a fixed range?  I can show you how to copy a different range depending on where the "Bin#" is found if that is what you want.

Comment: I dont mean to copy a fixed range. What i meant was, when i used another loop with ["Bin1" or "Bin2" or "Bin3" or "Bin4" or "Bin5", it copies Range("A2:G2") to Sheets("Sheet4")], i placed another name, say coldtest, by right it should not be copying it since its not within the condition, but in fact, coldtest was copied into sheet4. I cant post any pictures, if not i can make it even clearer to you...

Comment: I have added anothing section to my answer.  I hope this allows you to understand my confusion and I hope I have given the extra information you need.  Your last comment was posted at about 6:00 my time.  I will check for a response from you until about 23:00 my time.  After that, my internet access is being upgraded and may not work properly until Monday.  If I do not reply after today, it is because I cannot.

Comment: may i know how Syntax 3 is run? For this statement "If this(i) = that", am i suppose to change anything? I'm not in a rush, I can wait for your answer if I have any more questions. I will give it a try for all the syntax given. Thanks alot! :)

Comment: Sorry I was not clear.  `If this(i) = that then` was not supposed to be real code.  I wanted to show you `Exit For`.  However, `If this(i) = that then` could be real code.  `that` could be a variable or a literal.  `this` would an array and `this(i)` an entry in the array.  You could fill an array with the key values and then check then one at a time against the current value.  Look up arrays in VBA Help.  If it does not make sense, I will give you another example.

Comment: hmm... at the moment, i have combined some of the code with the one you have given earlier, it seems like it is a minor problem, if i have any problem, maybe i look for you? Thanks!

Comment: Come back any time.  I check Stack Exchange most days and it looks as though my upgrade was completed without any problems.